# Convert form input field contents to HTML5 datalist

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a working form which I would like to convert the input fields to use HTML5 datalists so that they autocomplete, I've tried various examples online but for some reason I an not getting it to work.

I should also add that the data starts off as a json file returned from an api which I convert into a array, might matter if there is a better way to do it starting from the json data.

Any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks

Gordon

Old working code

```
<select name="group[]">
    <option value=""></option>
    <?php
        foreach ($groups as $group) {
    ?>
        <option value="
            <?php echo $group["name"];?>">
            <?php echo $group["name"];?>
        </option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</select>
```

Latest attempt at new code

```
<input type="text" id="groups" list="groups" />
<datalist id="groups">
    <?php foreach ($groups as $group) {
            echo "<option value=" . $group['name'] . "</option>" ;
        }
    ?>
</datalist>
```

Solution, figured out after sleeping on it! hope it helps others

```
<input type="text" id="groups" list="group" id="grp"/>
  <datalist id="group">
     <?php foreach ($groups as $group) { ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $group['name']; ?>">
         <?php echo $group['name']; ?></option>
     <?php } ?>
</datalist>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why does your input tag and datalist tag have the same id? Also, you need to add a submit button as well. 
Also, as I see your code has a bug

```
echo "<option value=" . $group['name'] . "</option>" ;
```

should be,

```
echo "<option value=" . $group['name'] . "></option>" ;
                                          ^ closing tag. Missing here
```

The tag was not closed.

Link to a small working example fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/s3864qxy/1/

```
<input list="browsers" name="browser">
<datalist id="browsers">
   <option value="Internet Explorer">
   <option value="Firefox">
   <option value="Chrome">
   <option value="Opera">
   <option value="Safari">
</datalist>
<input type="submit">
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: *The tag was not closed.* - Sharp Eye.

Comment: Thanks for that I added the closing tag and changed the datalist etc so they have different id's but still no data in the field.
The submit is at the end of the form as there are other fields.